# Loading dynamic layout in react from a remote API response

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

How do I setup my react components in order to get the layout loaded from a remote rest based API? (I want the layout to be stored in a db so that it may be changed by the user whenever needed)

The API is a dot net core based API. It might be slightly difficult doing server side rendering. (Although that may be considered as well if there are no other options)

I essentially want to know if there is a way to send the jsx from the API. Is there then a way to return this jsx that I have received as the response from my component.

Comment: How your React code is packed and delivered? If you use webpack or browserify,  maybe you'll have to switch to requirejs.

Comment: Also, where do I report character escaping bugs in SO application?

Comment: First off, i love your username.

Comment: i am using webpack